# Python3 error when running a finite or infinite generator function

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, compiler-errors, generator

I would like to execute the following finite or infinite generator function (depending on the value of the keyword `terminate`) in Python3.4:

```
def generate_integers(begin,  terminate = None):
    k = begin
    while k<terminate or terminate==None:
        yield k
        k = k + 1
```

I run this function by the following command:

```
g = generate_integers(0) 
print(next(g))
print(next(g))
```

However, Python returns the following error message:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < NoneType()
```

I have problems interpreting this error because the function works well in two instances although these instances seems to me to be unrelated to the error message:

- When using only the conditional expression `while terminate==None:` in the `generate_integers(begin,terminate==None):` function, the function returns the desired values and no error message.
- The code runs well in Python2.7.6.

Can you explain the error message? Do you have and idea for tackling the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your test to first check if `terminate` is the `None` object:

```
while terminate is None or k < terminate:
```

`or` short-circuits; if `terminate is None` is true, the test for `k < terminate` is not executed.

Your code works in Python 2 because there Python tried to make everything orderable; `None` is sorted before integers only because Python tried to support sorting heterogenous lists. This turned out to be a source of hard-to-track bugs and the mistake was corrected in Python 3.

Note however, that your original code therefor would **not** work on Python 2 when `terminate = None` as `any_integer < None`, is *always False* on Python 2, at least for CPython. The language specification only states that the ordering between different types is stable, not what that order should be; Jython and IronPython are entirely free to sort `None` *after* integers.